# $_RM_S$ is R-projective and $_SN$ is S-projective then $_RM \otimes_S N$ is R-projective.

Tags: modules

I want to prove that if $_RM_S$ is R-projective and $_SN$ is S-projective then $_RM \otimes_S N$ is R-projective.

Projectivity of $_RM$ and $_SN \implies M \oplus K \cong R^{(I)}$ and $N \oplus L \cong S^{(J)}$

My question is: I want to construct $R^{(I)} \otimes_S S^{(J)} \cong (R \otimes S)^{(I \times J)}$ but are $K$ and $R^{(I)}$ S-Modules? How do I show that?

Maybe I see why $R^{(I)}$ is an S-Module (induced by $M_S$?), but $K$?

If in fact they are, the prove is clear.

$(R \otimes_S S)^{(I \times J)} \cong R^{(I)} \otimes_S S^{(J)} = (M \oplus K) \otimes_S (N \oplus L) = (M \otimes_S N) \oplus ((M \otimes_SL) \oplus (¿¿K \otimes_S (N \oplus K)??)) $

so $(M \otimes_S N)$ is a direct summand of a free R-module and hence R-projective.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $_SN$ is projective, there is $N'$ such that $N\oplus N'\cong S^{(I)}$ is a free module. Then we can tensor:
$$
M\otimes_SS^{(I)}\cong (M\otimes_SN)\oplus(M\otimes_SN')
$$
as $R$-modules. Now
$$
M\otimes_SS^{(I)}\cong M^{(I)}
$$
as $R$-modules. Since $M$ is projective, every direct power of it is projective as well. So $M\otimes_SN$ is a direct summand of a projective module.

Comment: So easy, Thanks!

Comment: @LuisVera I'd not say “easy”. The main point is indeed that we can't use the fact that $_RM$ is a summand of a free module, because the complement needn't be a bimodule. So we *have* to start from $N$.

Comment: that was precisely my problem but I forgot that $ \oplus_I P_i $ is projective $ \Leftrightarrow$  each $P_i $ is projective. Then the result follows.